# how to get attribute value in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

culd yu please tell me how to get attribute value in xslt?. I make variable in which I have `full name`(f) and `short name` (s).
using the full name I want to get short name

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMp/1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
      <xsl:variable name="teams">
            <team f="Sunrisers Hyderabad" s="SRH"></team>
            <team f="Delhi Daredevils" s="DD"></team>
            <team f="Gujarat Lions" s="GL"></team>
            <team f="Kings XI Punjab" s="KXIP"></team>
            <team f="Kolkata Knight Riders" s="KKR"></team>
            <team f="Mumbai Indians" s="MI"></team>
            <team f="Rising Pune Supergiant" s="RPS"></team>
            <team f="Royal Challengers Bangalore" s="RCB"></team>
 </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="up" select="'Kings XI Punjab'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($teams)/team[@f = $up]/@s"/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

**Expected output:
KXIP**

Comment: The posted code differs from the one you linked to and you have not provided any XML input in the question. Consider to add minimal but complete samples of input, XSLT, output you want and the result you get, together with a precise description of the XSLT processor you want to use as you have tagged the question as both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, have shown a `version="1.0"` stylesheet but used an XSLT 2.0 processor in your linked online editor. So we need more details to tell whether you need EXSLT at all and what the problem is.

Comment: I want to do this in xslt1

Comment: I want to do this in XSLT `1`

Comment: could you please help me out

Comment: Well, then use an XSLT 1.0 processor and then your code above works http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMp/3. If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor then remove the use of `exsl:node-set`, it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for help I am using XSLT 1

Comment: pls answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253447/how-to-show-only-two-items-in-xslt

Comment: @user944513 Being impatient or demanding does not really help here.

Answer (score -1):

See the edited code at http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMp/8 for your answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.