# how to show only two items in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

could yu please tell me how to show first two element is xslt ?
here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMp/6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="a">

      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="t"/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t[@live='2']">
<xsl:value-of select="@b"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**expected output : 12**

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the input XML please? xslttransform is great, but it is currently unavailable.... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to select the first two `t` elements which have the `live` attribute set to "2", you could put this logic in the `xsl:apply-templates` rather than the template match

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="t[@live='2'][position() &lt; = 2]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="a">

      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="t[@live='2'][position() &lt; = 2]"/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t">
<xsl:value-of select="@b"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```